# Reemplazar saltos de linea con párrafos en PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy editando código HTML mediante PHP. Estoy usando la función `str_replace`.

¿Cómo puedo identificar bloques de texto que están separados por saltos de linea y poner las etiquetas de párrafo?

Ejemplo:

Código HTML:

```
/n
Este es el contenido del párrafo.
/n
```

Resultado:

```
<p>
Este es el contenido del párrafo.
</p>
```

Comment: Daniel solo recuerda que los saltos de linea son definidos como \n no como /n, añadí una respuesta,  saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) se realizaría de esta forma:

```
$str = str_replace("\n", '<p>', $str);
```

y como mejor alternativa usando la constante que define "Fin de línea" [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php) :

```
$str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<p>', $str);
```

Un ejemplo:

```
<?php    
$str = "Hola Stackoverflow.com\nEste es el contenido del párrafo.
\nOtro paragraph";
$str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<p>', $str);
echo $str;
```

tendrías como resultado:

```html
    Hola Stackoverflow.com<p>Este es el contenido del párrafo.
    <p>Otro paragraph
```

Answer (score 1):

Amplío la respuesta de [Jorgesys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys) con un par de consideraciones:

- `PHP_EOL` es dependiente de la plataforma, si los strings fueron originados en la misma plataforma no hay problemas, si vienen de distintos orígenes un replace de `\n`(unix), `\r`(mac os no X) y `\r\n` (windows) sería lo mas compatible.
- Con sólo reemplazar por `<p>` no se está generando html válido, el navegador puede o no cerrar los tags y se verá bien, pero también puede malir sal.

Debido a esto tenemos que garantizar que se abren y se cierran los tags, una forma es usando `explode` para tener un array de todos los párrafos y luego un `implode` que va poniendo los tags. Algo así:

```
<?php
    function paragrafizar($string=""){
        // normalizamos los saltos de línea
        $string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $string);
        // creamos un array de parrafos
        $strParrafos = explode("\n", $string);
        // abrimos tag, deconstruimos el array, cerramos tag
        $string = '<p>' . implode("</p>\n<p>", $strParrafos) . '</p>';
        return $string;
    }

    $str1 = "Hola Stackoverflow.com\nEste es el contenido \rdel párrafo.\nOtro paragraph \r\ny Otro paragraph";
    $str2 = "Solo una línea";

    echo paragrafizar($str1). PHP_EOL;
    echo '---'. PHP_EOL;
    echo paragrafizar($str2). PHP_EOL;
```

---

Resultado:

```
<p>Hola Stackoverflow.com</p>
<p>Este es el contenido </p>
<p>del párrafo.</p>
<p>Otro paragraph </p>
<p>y Otro paragraph</p>
---
<p>Solo una línea</p>
```